# Check enable box whitout a mouse on an imac

Tags: imac

I have no mouse 
I have the keyboard full size

how do I check the enable box in mouse keys

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried using Tab key to move from field to field and then the space bar to select/deselect the checkboxes?

Comment: Do you have an extended keyboard? 5 is 'click' in mouse keys. idk how it works if you have a short keyboard with no 10-key.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which keyboard you have, the answer is different.

#### Standard Keyboard:

This assumes you have the standard, smaller keyboard shown here:
[image]
If this applies to you, then to click using Mouse Keys simply press `I`.

#### Extended Keyboard:

This assumes you have the extended, larger keyboard shown here:
[image]
If this applies to you, the to click using Mouse Keys simply press the `5` key **on the keypad on the right.**

Hope this helps!